# Points deducted, but not updated in reputation

Tags: bug, reputation

I recently became aware that my answer got deleted 4 hours ago.

My first question is, why did this question get deleted by the community, in spite of having answers, and marked as an answer:

[image: question]

The next mysterious one is the question for. The reputation log doesn't have the information after this was deleted.

[image: deleted answer]

So I checked my reputation for any changes, while I lost some 30 points (it was 3 votes then). When I checked my reputation page, I could not find an entry for this question.

[image: no entry]

Also, I have enabled to show the removed posts.

[image]

Is this a bug? Why is this happening? It's not even a community wiki. The link to the answer in concern: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34947079).

---

I have another question that was deleted:

[image: see]

Comment: When did this happen? It's probably caching

Comment: @Cai First line of the question is _"I recently came to know that my answer got deleted 4 hours ago."_ So... I would assume 4 hours ago.

Comment: @Cai Happening right now...

Comment: @Kendra Man, the issue is happening right now. The question was deleted four hours ago! LoL.

Comment: I guess Kendra means your wording is a little odd, that's all :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar When the post was deleted is what matters, for terms of caching. So, if it was deleted 4 hours ago (as I assumed from that line, rather than that you realized four hours ago that it was deleted) that's what Cai was wanting to know.

Comment: I'm sure that wasn't there before..... (the first screenshot definitely wasn't) damn ninja edits ;-)

Comment: But yeh "recently came to know that something happened 4 hours ago" doesn't necessarily mean it happened 4 hours ago :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/):

> if you've contributed something worthwhile to the site, you should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets deleted. "Worthwhile" here is defined as,
>
> - A score of 3 or greater
> - Visible on the site for at least 60 days

Since your answer had score of 3 and it was posted over 60 days ago, you indeed don't lose the reputation, so there's nothing to show in your reputation history for the time when the answer was deleted.

Comment: Now this makes sense... Thanks a lot for this. `:)` Out of curiosity, do you work at Stack Exchange? You seem to know a lot about the platform. Is there a platform doc available?

Comment: @PraveenKumar wait, I was wrong. Your answer has score of 2, not 3, so you shouldn't keep the reputation. You will see the -20 if you tick "show removed posts" in your reputation page.

Comment: I ticked everything mate (including your answer's tick button ;)). It was showing as 3 before.

Comment: But wait, see, when I check the `/reputation` page, I couldn't find the number `34947079`, which is the answer's ID. Weird. Ultimately the reputation is lost. But it is just not showing. Crazy. Let's wait for other answers like you said.

Comment: @PraveenKumar so maybe the upvote by the removed user has been removed, meaning you had 3 indeed. Only a dev can confirm that, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah buddy, this is confusing... Let's wait for a while, else I'll accept your answer. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the owner of the question requested account deletion and that along with the account, all the downvoted questions were removed. This is by default as far as I know.

<strike>Deleted posts don't end up in your reputation overview since it is like they never existed.</strike> Nonsense. Of course they do. Shadow Wizard has a better analysis of the missing reputation change in [his post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284761/245360).

Comment: The show deleted posts will show that the post has been deleted. I don't think this is the case.

Comment: I have a deleted post I lost rep from that shows in my reputation tab, when I check the checkbox. _"Deleted posts don't end up in your reputation overview since it is like they never existed."_ What would be the point of the checkbox then?

Comment: Kindly check out the updated question bud...

Comment: The user did get deleted at that time according to [the timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34947033/timeline). @PraveenKumar

Comment: Regarding your edit, you're correct for most cases of answers deleted before they're 60 days old, and/or got score of less than 3.